# Parameter passed into JS function is "undefined" on IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer, safari

With the below HTML and Javascript code, I'm finding that in IE11 and Safari on iOS the form isn't passing the value of the "choice" radio buttons. Using an alert() function I can see that "answer" is undefined, wheras in Chrone and Firefox it has the expected value of "right" or "wrong".

Does anyone have suggestions for how to fix this? 
And by extension: why is it not behaving as I would expect in IE and Safari?

HTML:

```
    <form>
        <p><label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="right" />Choice One</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="wrong" />Choice Two</label></p>
        <p><input type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="checkThing(choice.value)"></p>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function checkThing(answer){
    if(answer == "right"){
        //Show one thing
    }
    else if(answer == "wrong"){
        //show another thing
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems as if IE doesn't register names as globals, but Firefox and Chrome do, just guessing

Answer (score 0):

It is a little convoluted, but you have to iterate to get things working in Internet Explorer.

I have added an id and removed the argument from the `onclick` event - working (cross browser) version below:

```js
function checkThing(){
    var answers = document.getElementById('myform').elements['choice'];
    for(var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        if (answers[i].checked === true) {
            answer = answers[i].value;   
        }
    }
    
    alert(answer);
}
```

```html
   <form id="myform">
        <p><label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="right" />Choice One</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="radio" name="choice" value="wrong" />Choice Two</label></p>
        <p><input type="button" value="Check Answer" onclick="checkThing(choice.value)"></p>
    </form>
```